# fill a dataframe with value of another dataframe according to columns value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, fill

I have two dataframe:

the first one, let's say dfrA

```
x,y,z
0,0,1
0,1,2
0,2,3
0,3,4
1,0,5
1,1,6
1,2,7
1,3,8
2,0,9
2,1,10
2,2,11
2,3,12
3,0,13
3,1,14
3,2,15
3,3,16
```

and another one, let's say dfrB

```
x,y
1,2
2,3
```

I would like to add a column in dfrB according with z value in the dfrA which has the same x and y of the dfrB.

In other words I expect:

```
x,y,z
1,2,7
2,3,12
```

I am able to a empty column to dfrB:

```
df_support = pd.DataFrame(columns=['z'])
dfrB = dfrB.join(df_support, how="outer")
```

how can now fill column z in dfrB? I would like to avoid to do a cycle full of if.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [`pandas.DataFrame.merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html)

```py
dfrB['z'] = dfrB.merge(dfrA, on=['x', 'y'], how='left')['z']
```

```
print(dfrB)

   x  y   z
0  1  2   7
1  2  3  12
```